# Is it possible to load a visualization created in the Carto Builder using Carto VL?

Tags: carto, carto-vl

When using CARTO VL to load data from my Carto account I'm able to add Datasets to the map and interact with it.

Is there any way to add the whole map built in the Carto builder to a map? With all its layers?

I suppose I can load it as regular raster tiles, but I'd like to receive each layer (dataset) information so I can programatically add interaction to it. (I'm assuming it's not possible to have the programmed interaction working as we have when using CARTO.js)

Answer (score 0):

This is not currently possible, the only way is to use the datasets as you mention from CARTO VL and then apply manually in CARTO VL the styles and the interaction.

Comment: Thanks @elena-torró, I was almost sure it was not possible but I had to ask. In this case, I might add it as raster tiles but still I would like to add the interaction. Can you have a look at https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/341110/how-to-list-all-columns-of-a-dataset ?