# List all columns of a dataset?

Tags: javascript, carto, carto-vl

Using CARTO VL.

Having a dataset, is there a way to fetch all columns this dataset has before I create the viz object so I can programmatically decide which variables to add to the viz?

Something like:

```
const source = new carto.source.Dataset('my-dataset');
const columns = source.getColumns();
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer I found so far is to make a request to the SQL API.

So, for now, I'm doing:

```
        $.ajax({
            url: 'https://{USERNAME}.carto.com/api/v2/sql',
            data: {
                api_key: {API_KEY},
                q: 'SELECT CDB_ColumnNames('{TABLE}')',

            },
            success: function(results) {
                // Get columns:
                var c = results.rows.map(r => {
                    return r.cdb_columnnames;
                })
                console.log(c);
            }

        });
```